# How to forward email of a specific sender from Outlook.com to Gmail?

Tags: outlook.com, email-forwarding

I got an Outlook.com account which I use to subscribe to some mail lists. I want to forward the emails of one of the lists to my Gmail account, but the only option I see is to forward everything, so how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a rule to forward email from a specific sender to an email address:

- Click the **Gear** in the upper right hand corner of the screen and click on **Manage Rules**
- Click on **New**
- In `Step 1` you should select which messages you want to be forwarded
- In `Step 2` you can select `Forward to` and input the email address where you want the emails to go

  - (You must have verified this email address in order for this to work)
- Click **Save** when your done

Comment: Ohh, I hadn't seen the rules options, just the filters.

Answer (score 0):

Just like other Outlook products, you need to set up [rules](http://email.about.com/od/Outlook.com-Tips/qt/How-To-Forward-Outlook-Com-Email-To-Another-Email-Address.htm) to forward the email.